# Cant initialize with __init__()

Tags: python, class, methods

I am trying to initialize a value with

> **init()**

, but when I try to display value I get some other error(as seen in the screenshot).

Please let me know where I am going wrong?

[image]

Comment: That's not an error, it's what python prints to represent a function. You're printing a function without calling it - i.e. you're printing the function object itself, not what it returns when it's ran. Try `ff.showvalue()`.

Comment: Please add your code and output as formatted text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

The initialization is fine. The problem is in how you call the method. As the commenters point out, you made a typo and forgot to add the `()`. `self.showValue()` gives the result of the function, `self.showValue` just gives a handle to the function itself.

Comment: Oh yes ,sorry I did not see that.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're printing the function of a class:

`self.showValue`

instead of:

`self.value`

Full running:

```
In [2]: class what:
   ...:     def __init__(self, a):
   ...:         self.value = a
   ...:     def show_value(self):
   ...:         print(self.value)
   ...:         

In [3]: w = what(6)

In [4]: w.show_value()
    6
```

You better put it in `__str__()` though